# PHP XML - Child nodes retriving data

Tags: php, xml, nodes, children

I have a problem in php. I can only retrive the value of the fist tag.

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<reservation id="000020" internalId="7366776" > 
   <ccData ccExpireDate="null/null" />
   <reservationDetail id="2_0" currency="" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-08-01" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-08-02" />
</reservation>
<reservation id="000010" internalId="7366642" >
   <ccData ccCode="Michan" ccNumber="3000000000000" ccExpireDate="12/2016"  />
   <reservationDetail id="2_0" currency="USD" checkin="2015-07-01" />
   <supplement detailId="" roomId="2" description="breakfast" />
   <supplement detailId="" roomId="2" description="wifi" />
   <supplement detailId="" roomId="2" description="transfer" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-06-01" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-06-02" />
   <guest detailId="" roomId="2" firstName="Rolando" />
   <guest detailId="" roomId="2" firstName="Jessica " />
</reservation>
<reservation id="0005" internalId="7243828" >
   <ccData ccCode="453" ccNumber="34983483649365936539" ccExpireDate="05/2016" />
   <reservationDetail id="2_0" currency="USD" checkin="2015-05-28" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-05-29" />
   <dayPrice detailId="" roomId="2" day="2015-05-29" />
</reservation>
</Response>
```

And this is the code of the php to retrive the data

```
//SUPPLEMENT
$Cont=0;
echo "SUP >>>>> ".count($xml->reservation[$x]->supplement)."<br>";  
do {    
    foreach($xml->reservation[$x]->supplement->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        $Texto='[SUPPLEMENT '.sprintf('%02d', $Cont).'] '.$a.'="'.utf8_decode($b).'"';
        echo $Texto."<br>";         
    }
    $Cont++;
} while ($Cont > 99);
```

This this code the output is this

```
[SUPPLEMENT 00] detailId=""
[SUPPLEMENT 00] roomId="2"
[SUPPLEMENT 00] description="breakfast"
```

Instead of this

```
[SUPPLEMENT 00] detailId=""
[SUPPLEMENT 00] roomId="2"
[SUPPLEMENT 01] description="breakfast"
[SUPPLEMENT 01] detailId=""
[SUPPLEMENT 01] roomId="2"
[SUPPLEMENT 01] description="wifi"
[SUPPLEMENT 02] detailId=""
[SUPPLEMENT 02] roomId="2"
[SUPPLEMENT 02] description="transfer"
```

is the same problem this the tags dayPrice and guest.

Can anybody help me ?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop is only going through the attributes of a single `supplement`. You need another one to loop though each `supplement` and the next one to loop through each attribute:

```
do {
    foreach($xml->reservation[$x]->supplement as $supplement) {  
      foreach($supplement->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        $Texto='[SUPPLEMENT '.sprintf('%02d', $Cont).'] '.$a.'="'.utf8_decode($b).'"';
        echo $Texto."<br>";         
      }
    }
    $Cont++;
} while ($Cont > 99);
```

*Note*: `$x` is `1` in your case.